# What's the best way for Cypress test to communicate with the React app?

Tags: reactjs, testing, next.js, cypress

I have four separate Cypress tests with ID test1, test2 and test3, and another one without any ID. I want my app to call three different apis based on the test id. What's the best way for Cypress to pass information to the app?

```
To run test without an id, call http://www.myapi.com/data
To run test with id test1, call http://www.myapi.com/data?id=test1
To run test with id test2, call http://www.myapi.com/data?id=test2
To run test with id test3, call http://www.myapi.com/data?id=test3
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming you are using `http://www.myapi.com/data?id=test1` in a `cy.visit()` command.

You can use string interpolation to change the URL parameter, roughly

```js
['test1', 'test2', 'test3`].forEach(param => {

  it(`Tests with ${param}`, () => {
    cy.visit(`http://www.myapi.com/data?id=${param}`)
    ...
  })
})
```

or in `cy.request()`

```js
['test1', 'test2', 'test3`].forEach(param => {

  const url = `http://www.myapi.com/data?id=${param}`
  cy.request(url).then(response => {
    ...
  })
})
```

Comment: Is there a way to persist the URL params as the Cypress test clicks from page to page? In addition, we have various components that make similar call multiple times. Is there a way to read the url param at the middleware level so I only write this interception logic once?